# mongoose populate inside of nested object

Tags: mongoose, nested, populate

I want to use populate() inside of an nested object. 
Populate seems to resolve something but it returns [Object].

I found a lot of Answers for more complex examples of populate() but i didnt find anything for this problem.

This is what i get from the query:

```
 User: [{ 
            General: { Name: 'testUsername' },
            data: { car_ref: [Object] },
            _id: ...
          }]
```

This is what i want to have:

```
User: [{ 
        General: { Name: 'testUsername' },
        data: { car_ref: { Name: 'testCarname' } },
        _id: ...
      }]
```

Calling find() without populate gets me the correct _id of my car-Document.

```
 User: [{ 
            General: { Name: 'testUsername' },
            data: { car_ref: 5bfbe82402f3a8354892dbd7 },
            _id: ...
          }]
```

This is my call of populate function:

```
 userModel
        .find()
        .populate({path:"data.car_ref"});
```

My schemas look like this:

```
userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  General: { Name: "Testname"}
  data: {
     car_ref:{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "car" 
      }
 });

carSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  carName: String
});
```

This is how my car entry looks like:

```
 Car: [{ _id: ..., Name: 'testCarname' }]
```

Comment: Are you sure the output is not truncated for brevity by the console log? (yes, that's a thing!)  Try to JSON.stringify before output to make sure. Or output something that is nested deeper, like `console.log(users[0].data.car_ref);`

Comment: Or `console.dir(users)`

Comment: well... that was it! its working now. Thanks!